# Move whole site up or move cart down?

Tags: css, woocommerce

Im working on this Woocommcerce shop: http://oliver.kaspertoxvig.dk/
I want to have the logo closer to the top of the page like this: http://screencast.com/t/TgrzkfcNWm
, but I can´t figure out how to do this.

Comment: `div#top` takes up some space at the top of the page. Also, `header#header` has top padding. Please show us what you've tried and what went wrong.

Comment: 1. Problems with code need to be included in your question 2. Use screenshots, not links to your page.

Comment: Sorry I did not know the rule about linking.
And I tried to post a image, but I haven´t enough points :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give the #logo a negative top margin

-or-

you can make the #top div skinnier (something like 25%) and float it to the right, and make the #header div skinnier (something like 75%) and it will push itself up into the empty space to the left of the #top div.